# Apostrophe default value

Tags: apostrophe-cms

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    label: 'Learn More',
    instructions: 'Learn More Widgets',
    addFields: [
        {
            name: 'learnMore',
            type: 'string',
            label: 'Name for the Link',
            required: false,
        },

    ]
};
```

How can we set the default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

Just use the `def` property:

```
{
  name: 'learnMore',
  type: 'string',
  label: 'Name for the Link',
  required: false,
  def: 'Learn More'
}
```

Comment: How do I add default selected for select type with choices?

Comment: It's the same. Set `def` to match the `value` of the choice you want to be the default.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work in apostrophe cms version 2.37.2